# Calculating the True Error of a Distribution

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions

I am currently studying "Understanding Machine Learning from Theory to Practice" written by Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Shai Ben-David. I am a bit confused about an example regarding the calculation of the True Error of a Distribution that the author presented in one of his lectures on YouTube. Let $X=\{a,b\}$ our Domain and $Y=\{1,0\}$ our Labels and $D$ our probability distribution over $X\times Y$:

\begin{equation}
D(a) = D(b) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
D(1 | a) = D(0 | b) = \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D(0 | a) = D(1 | b) = \frac{1}{2} - \epsilon
\end{equation}
Let H be our Hypotheis Class consisting of two function:
\begin{equation}
H=\{h_1,h_2\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h_1(a)=1,h_1(b)=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
h_2(a)=0,h_2(b)=1
\end{equation}
Then the true error of $h_1,h_2$ is
\begin{equation}
L_D(h_1)=D(\{(x,y):h_1(x)\neq y\})=D((a,0))+D((b,1))=1/2-\epsilon
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
L_D(h_2)=D(\{(x,y):h_2(x)\neq y\})=D((a,1))+D((b,0))=1/2+\epsilon
\end{equation}

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing chain rule step which is $D((a,0))=D(a)D(0|a)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2} - \epsilon), D((b,1))=D(b)D(1|b)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2} - \epsilon)$

So after straightforward substituting  your results are both correct.